# CSS 'background-image' not resizing correctly

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm in the midst of making a navigation bar. I came here earlier and got some help re-organising and coding said item. All seemed great and it seemed like it should work but when using the following code instead of each image resizing, it only showed X% of the images height and Y% of the images width. I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

CSS:

```
#navbar a.newr:link { background-image: url('newr.png'); display: block; width: 5%; height: 2%; }

#navbar a.newr:hover { background-image: url('newrhover.png'); display: block; width: 5%; height: 2%; }
```

Please refer to [how it looks looks on my website](http://www.step-down.co.uk) to see what I mean.
Please also refer to [my other navbar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677702/resizable-nav-bar)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Background images don't resize. They are shown in full size and are clipped if the container is smaller.

What you can do:

- The best approach is to resize the images to the target size
- A hackish approach is to use absolutely positioned `<img>` tags as background and `<span>` text as foreground.

  ```
  <div class="hasBg">
      <img>
      <span>text</span>
  <div>

  .hasBg{
      position:relative;
  }
  //will autofit depending on how span stretches the container
  .hasBg img{
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
  }

  .hasBg span{
      position:absolute;
  }
  ```
- A native but new feature is to use the new CSS3 [`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/). but this is not cross-browser afaik

Comment: Regarding CSS compatibility, a great website to use is CanIUse.com, here's background-size http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size.  Looks like it might have good support except for that very important IE pool.  I'm not sure if there's a JS polyfill work-around for it.  But one could use Modernizr to craft and alternative experience for those without it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've done it as a background image, the width and height attributes only apply to the div, not the image.

You have two options.

- Resize your images to fit the dimensions
- have your images on your page and use javascript for your hover effect